# sc_reduce32 not working for mnemonic generation?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery, wallet, privatekey, spend-key

I'm working on an address generator that's comptaible with the Monero GUI. My seed generator works, however I still don't understand why [Crypto Address Test](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) gets a different result when it creates the Private Spend Key from the hexadecimal seed.

With a hexadecimal seed *af7a0c64ff778aba9070b7de1bff243aa8496074608fc1c03625da2bf00dba95* [Crypto Address Test](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) generates *5a07681f12fce4a107ed022448364e7ea7496074608fc1c03625da2bf00dba05* as the private spend key instead of the original value.

Is there something wrong with my ScReduce32 function?

**Here's my code:**

```
fun generateMnemonicSeed(): String {
    val spendKey = generateEdDSAKeyPair()
    val spendPriv = (spendKey.private as Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters).encoded
    println("B4 sc_reduce32: ${spendPriv.toHex()}")
    val reduced =ScReduce32(spendPriv.toHex())
    println("After sc_reduce32: $reduced")
    return hexToSeedPhrase(reduced)
}
fun ScReduce32(hexString: String): String{
    println("hexString:$hexString")
    val j = BigInteger(hexString, 16)
    println("j: $j")
    println("j-hex: ${j.toString(16)}")
    val l = (BigInteger.valueOf(2L).pow(256) + BigInteger("27742317777372353535851937790883648493"))
    println("l: ${l.toString(16)}")
    val reduced = j % l
    val reducedStr = reduced.toString(16)
    println("reducedStr: ${reduced.toString(16)}")
    return reducedStr
}
```

**Resulting Logs**

```
B4 sc_reduce32: af7a0c64ff778aba9070b7de1bff243aa8496074608fc1c03625da2bf00dba95
hexString:af7a0c64ff778aba9070b7de1bff243aa8496074608fc1c03625da2bf00dba95
j: 79370389387829220119965404010432066765120076533697599508186610358111351716501
j-hex: af7a0c64ff778aba9070b7de1bff243aa8496074608fc1c03625da2bf00dba95
l: 10000000000000000000000000000000014def9dea2f79cd65812631a5cf5d3ed
reducedStr: af7a0c64ff778aba9070b7de1bff243aa8496074608fc1c03625da2bf00dba95
After sc_reduce32: af7a0c64ff778aba9070b7de1bff243aa8496074608fc1c03625da2bf00dba95
toMnemonic: af7a0c64ff778aba9070b7de1bff243aa8496074608fc1c03625da2bf00dba95
n: 1626
new tmpStr: 640c7aafba8a77ffdeb770903a24ff1b746049a8c0c18f602bda253695ba0df0
words: [avidly, water, goldfish, utensils, people, hiding, sawmill, ambush, upper, island, hubcaps, orbit, jellyfish, vary, hinder, vain, baptism, terminal, exotic, morsel, return, lion, oozed, dime]
str: aviwatgolutepeohidsawambuppislhuborbjelvarhinvaibapterexomorretliooozdim
words.joinToString(" "): avidly water goldfish utensils people hiding sawmill ambush upper island hubcaps orbit jellyfish vary hinder vain baptism terminal exotic morsel return lion oozed dime
words.joinToString(" ").length: 167
r2:0
checkSumWord: avidly
resultList.size: 25
mnemonicSeed:avidly water goldfish utensils people hiding sawmill ambush upper island hubcaps orbit jellyfish vary hinder vain baptism terminal exotic morsel return lion oozed dime avidly
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the code snippet:

```
fun scReduce32(s: UByteArray): UByteArray {
    var s0 = 2097151 and load3(s)
    var s1 = 2097151 and (load4(s.copyOfRange(2, 6)) shr 5)
    var s2 = 2097151 and (load3(s.copyOfRange(5, 8)) shr 2)
    var s3 = 2097151 and (load4(s.copyOfRange(7, 11)) shr 7)
    var s4 = 2097151 and (load4(s.copyOfRange(10, 14)) shr 4)
    var s5 = 2097151 and (load3(s.copyOfRange(13, 16)) shr 1)
    var s6 = 2097151 and (load4(s.copyOfRange(15, 19)) shr 6)
    var s7 = 2097151 and (load3(s.copyOfRange(18, 21)) shr 3)
    var s8 = 2097151 and load3(s.copyOfRange(21, 24))
    var s9 = 2097151 and (load4(s.copyOfRange(23, 27)) shr 5)
    var s10 = 2097151 and (load3(s.copyOfRange(26, 29)) shr 2)
    var s11 = load4(s.copyOfRange(28, 32)) shr 7
    var s12 = 0
    val carry = IntArray(12)

    carry[0] = (s0 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s1 += carry[0]
    s0 -= carry[0] shl 21
    carry[2] = (s2 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s3 += carry[2]
    s2 -= carry[2] shl 21
    carry[4] = (s4 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s5 += carry[4]
    s4 -= carry[4] shl 21
    carry[6] = (s6 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s7 += carry[6]
    s6 -= carry[6] shl 21
    carry[8] = (s8 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s9 += carry[8]
    s8 -= carry[8] shl 21
    carry[10] = (s10 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s11 += carry[10]
    s10 -= carry[10] shl 21

    carry[1] = (s1 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s2 += carry[1]
    s1 -= carry[1] shl 21
    carry[3] = (s3 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s4 += carry[3]
    s3 -= carry[3] shl 21
    carry[5] = (s5 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s6 += carry[5]
    s5 -= carry[5] shl 21
    carry[7] = (s7 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s8 += carry[7]
    s7 -= carry[7] shl 21
    carry[9] = (s9 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s10 += carry[9]
    s9 -= carry[9] shl 21
    carry[11] = (s11 + (1 shl 20)) shr 21
    s12 += carry[11]
    s11 -= carry[11] shl 21

    s0 += s12 * 666643
    s1 += s12 * 470296
    s2 += s12 * 654183
    s3 -= s12 * 997805
    s4 += s12 * 136657
    s5 -= s12 * 683901
    s12 = 0

    carry[0] = s0 shr 21
    s1 += carry[0]
    s0 -= carry[0] shl 21
    carry[1] = s1 shr 21
    s2 += carry[1]
    s1 -= carry[1] shl 21
    carry[2] = s2 shr 21
    s3 += carry[2]
    s2 -= carry[2] shl 21
    carry[3] = s3 shr 21
    s4 += carry[3]
    s3 -= carry[3] shl 21
    carry[4] = s4 shr 21
    s5 += carry[4]
    s4 -= carry[4] shl 21
    carry[5] = s5 shr 21
    s6 += carry[5]
    s5 -= carry[5] shl 21
    carry[6] = s6 shr 21
    s7 += carry[6]
    s6 -= carry[6] shl 21
    carry[7] = s7 shr 21
    s8 += carry[7]
    s7 -= carry[7] shl 21
    carry[8] = s8 shr 21
    s9 += carry[8]
    s8 -= carry[8] shl 21
    carry[9] = s9 shr 21
    s10 += carry[9]
    s9 -= carry[9] shl 21
    carry[10] = s10 shr 21
    s11 += carry[10]
    s10 -= carry[10] shl 21
    carry[11] = s11 shr 21
    s12 += carry[11]
    s11 -= carry[11] shl 21

    s0 += s12 * 666643
    s1 += s12 * 470296
    s2 += s12 * 654183
    s3 -= s12 * 997805
    s4 += s12 * 136657
    s5 -= s12 * 683901

    carry[0] = s0 shr 21
    s1 += carry[0]
    s0 -= carry[0] shl 21
    carry[1] = s1 shr 21
    s2 += carry[1]
    s1 -= carry[1] shl 21
    carry[2] = s2 shr 21
    s3 += carry[2]
    s2 -= carry[2] shl 21
    carry[3] = s3 shr 21
    s4 += carry[3]
    s3 -= carry[3] shl 21
    carry[4] = s4 shr 21
    s5 += carry[4]
    s4 -= carry[4] shl 21
    carry[5] = s5 shr 21
    s6 += carry[5]
    s5 -= carry[5] shl 21
    carry[6] = s6 shr 21
    s7 += carry[6]
    s6 -= carry[6] shl 21
    carry[7] = s7 shr 21
    s8 += carry[7]
    s7 -= carry[7] shl 21
    carry[8] = s8 shr 21
    s9 += carry[8]
    s8 -= carry[8] shl 21
    carry[9] = s9 shr 21
    s10 += carry[9]
    s9 -= carry[9] shl 21
    carry[10] = s10 shr 21
    s11 += carry[10]
    s10 -= carry[10] shl 21

    s[0] = s0.toUByte()
    s[1] = (s0 shr 8).toUByte()
    s[2] = ((s0 shr 16) or (s1 shl 5)).toUByte()
    s[3] = (s1 shr 3).toUByte()
    s[4] = (s1 shr 11).toUByte()
    s[5] = ((s1 shr 19) or (s2 shl 2)).toUByte()
    s[6] = (s2 shr 6).toUByte()
    s[7] = ((s2 shr 14) or (s3 shl 7)).toUByte()
    s[8] = (s3 shr 1).toUByte()
    s[9] = (s3 shr 9).toUByte()
    s[10] = ((s3 shr 17) or (s4 shl 4)).toUByte()
    s[11] = (s4 shr 4).toUByte()
    s[12] = (s4 shr 12).toUByte()
    s[13] = ((s4 shr 20) or (s5 shl 1)).toUByte()
    s[14] = (s5 shr 7).toUByte()
    s[15] = ((s5 shr 15) or (s6 shl 6)).toUByte()
    s[16] = (s6 shr 2).toUByte()
    s[17] = (s6 shr 10).toUByte()
    s[18] = ((s6 shr 18) or (s7 shl 3)).toUByte()
    s[19] = (s7 shr 5).toUByte()
    s[20] = (s7 shr 13).toUByte()
    s[21] = s8.toUByte()
    s[22] = (s8 shr 8).toUByte()
    s[23] = ((s8 shr 16) or (s9 shl 5)).toUByte()
    s[24] = (s9 shr 3).toUByte()
    s[25] = (s9 shr 11).toUByte()
    s[26] = ((s9 shr 19) or (s10 shl 2)).toUByte()
    s[27] = (s10 shr 6).toUByte()
    s[28] = ((s10 shr 14) or (s11 shl 7)).toUByte()
    s[29] = (s11 shr 1).toUByte()
    s[30] = (s11 shr 9).toUByte()
    s[31] = (s11 shr 17).toUByte()

    return s
}
```